# How to solve Rate Exceed error for AWS microservices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, performance-testing

I am doing performance testing on AWS micro services with 50 users and ramp up time is 10 seconds.

However, some of the requests are giving "rate Exceed" error. The microservices are getting the data from S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are suffering from [rate limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting) you need to either slow down your tests to the supported level of requests per unit of time using [Pacing](http://www.quotium.com/performance/load-testing-calculating-pacing-time/) or a special configuration element like [Constant Throughput Timer in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/). Another possibility is that your application is limiting the number of requests from a single IP so you might want to implement some form of [IP Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) so each user would have its own source IP address
2. If there is no artificial limiting of the requests rate in your application and you're getting this error from S3 you need to follow recommendations from [Best Practices Design Patterns: Optimizing Amazon S3 Performance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html) article